# Insert into websql via Ajax feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-sql

Ok i'm having a play trying to get some code working and not having much luck with my current set-up, but not sure how to change it around either...

The error i'm getting is:
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

So i'm guessing the data connection is not available by the time it gets to adding the data?

Any help, pointers more than welcome!

```
var WebSqlStore = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var eventsURL='http://www.url.com/api/eventsWEBSQL.php';

    this.initializeDatabase = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var self = this;

        this.db = window.openDatabase("AADB", "1.0", "App DB", 200000);
        this.db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                self.createEvents(tx);
                self.addEvents(tx);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Transaction error: ' + error);
                if (errorCallback) errorCallback();
            },
            function() {
                console.log('Transaction success');
                if (successCallback) successCallback();
            }
        )
    }

    this.createEvents = function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events');
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "userid INTEGER, " +
            "name VARCHAR(255), " +
            "subname VARCHAR(255), " +
            "startdate DATETIME, " +
            "duration VARCHAR(255), " +
            "location VARCHAR(100), " +
            "address VARCHAR(255), " +
            "city VARCHAR(255), " +
            "county VARCHAR(255), " +
            "postcode VARCHAR(15), " +
            "telephone VARCHAR(20), " +
            "modules VARCHAR(255), " +
            "description TEXT, " +
            "feedback TEXT, " +
            "archive INTEGER, " +
            "live INTEGER" +
    ")";
    tx.executeSql(sql, null,
        function() {
            console.log('Create table success');
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            alert('Create table error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }

        this.addEvents = function(tx) {


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: eventsURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { LN: 0 },
            success:function (data) {           
                 var events = data

                     var l = events.length;
                     //console.log("Events length: "+l);
                     var sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO events " +
                       "(id, userid, name, subname, startdate, duration, location, address, city, county, postcode, telephone, modules, description, feedback, archive, live) " + //16
                       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                     var e;
                     for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                       e = events[i];
                       tx.executeSql(sql, [e.id, e.userid, e.name, e.subname, e.startdate, e.duration, e.location, e.address, e.city, e.county, e.postcode, e.telephone, e.modules, e.description, e.feedback, e.archive, e.live],
                        function() {
                            console.log('INSERT success');
                        },
                        function(tx, error) {
                            alert('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                        }
                       );
                     }
        },
        error:function(error) {
            app.showAlert("Internet access is required to get new items, Will continue using local data ", "Events");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    } //End addEvents

    this.initializeDatabase(successCallback, errorCallback);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone who is like me and finding there own way... the solution was to add another connection:

```
    var WebSqlStore = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {

    var eventsURL='http://www.url.com/api/eventsWEBSQL.php';

    var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    var webdb = openDatabase("AADB", "1.0", "App DB", dbSize);  

    this.initializeDatabase = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var self = this;

        this.db = webdb;
        this.db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                self.createEvents(tx);
                self.addEvents(tx);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Transaction error: ' + error);
                if (errorCallback) errorCallback();
            },
            function() {
                console.log('Transaction success');
                if (successCallback) successCallback();
            }
        )
    }

    this.createEvents = function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events');
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "userid INTEGER, " +
            "name VARCHAR(255), " +
            "subname VARCHAR(255), " +
            "startdate DATETIME, " +
            "duration VARCHAR(255), " +
            "location VARCHAR(100), " +
            "address VARCHAR(255), " +
            "city VARCHAR(255), " +
            "county VARCHAR(255), " +
            "postcode VARCHAR(15), " +
            "telephone VARCHAR(20), " +
            "modules VARCHAR(255), " +
            "description TEXT, " +
            "feedback TEXT, " +
            "archive INTEGER, " +
            "live INTEGER" +
    ")";
    tx.executeSql(sql, null,
        function() {
            console.log('Create table success');
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            alert('Create table error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }

        this.addEvents = function(tx) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: eventsURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { LN: 0 },
            success:this.insertEvents,
                error:function(error) {
                app.showAlert("Internet access is required to get new items, Will continue using local data ", "Events");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

        } //End addEvents

    this.insertEvents = function(data) {
        this.db = webdb;
        this.db.transaction(
        function(tx) {      
            var events = data

                var l = events.length;
                console.log("Events length: "+l);

                var sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO events " +
                  "(id, userid, name, subname, startdate, duration, location, address, city, county, postcode, telephone, modules, description, feedback, archive, live) " + //16
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                var e;
                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                  e = events[i];
                  tx.executeSql(sql, [e.id, e.userid, e.name, e.subname, e.startdate, e.duration, e.location, e.address, e.city, e.county, e.postcode, e.telephone, e.modules, e.description, e.feedback, e.archive, e.live],
                    function() {
                        console.log('INSERT success');
                    },
                    function(tx, error) {
                        alert('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                    }
                  );
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```